Joint probability table not adding up to 1
I got this question asked in my exam today:
Suppose there is a group of 9 students that belong to a university. 4 of them study economics, 3 of them study business and the rest study engineer. Suppose 2 of the students are chosen randomly with replacement. Let the variables $X$ and $Y$ be:
$X$: Number of students that study economics in the sample of 2
$Y$: Number of students that study business in the sample of 2
Build the joint probability table for variables X and Y:
X and Y can take the values $0$, $1$ and $2$, so table has 3 rows and 3 columns, but if $X+Y>3$, $P(X \cap Y)=0$ because the sample size would be greater than $2$; for example, $P(X=2 \cap Y=1)=0$ since the sample size would be 3 (or that´s what I think). The "problem" is that the rows and the columns don´t add up to one:


The $(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$ entries are under-counted by a factor of two, probably because you forgot that there are two orders in which you can sample the two different degrees that appear in each of those entries. Next time please show your work and preferably express things as fractions as it's easier to check your answers that way.

@BenjaminWang Yeah you are right, now it adds up to one. It´s because there two ways of having the entries you said right? For example, for (1,1), the sample could be business/econ or econ/business (something like the combination of the binomial distribution?)
PD: So that´s why this question was worth 3 points out of 20 and all the other questions were worth between 1.5 and 2.5 points
